# How can I read a file having different column for each rows?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

my data looks like this.

0 199 1028 251 1449 847 1483 1314 23 1066 604 398 225 552 1512 1598

1 1214 910 631 422 503 183 887 342 794 590 392 874 1223 314 276 1411

2 1199 700 1717 450 1043 540 552 101 359 219 64 781 953

10 1707 1019 463 827 675 874 470 943 667 237 1440 892 677 631 425

How can I read this file structure in python? I want to extract a specific column from rows. For example, If I want to extract value in the second row, second column, how can I do that? I've tried 'loadtxt' using data type string. But it requires string index slicing, so that I could not proceed because each column has different digits. Moreover, each row has a different number of columns. Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you transpose it?

Comment: Use split method for strings.

Comment: Read a line as a string. Split it to get a list of individual numbers as strings. Map them to get a list of integers. Read them as you like.

Comment: If the rows all have different number of items - what is the structure and its meaning then? How would you define what is a column here? Just fill too short rows with `NaN`? or shorten the too long rows? Too much guessing needed up to now, please try to precisely describe what you want, what you already did and why it failed, i.e.: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to split it

`split2=[]
split1=txt.split("\n")
for item in split1:
    split2.append(item.split(" "))`

Comment: Note that `space` is the standard separator of `str.split()` so it's not necessary to explicitly set it. And as OP is asking about a file in which the data resides, you would better do sth like `rows = []; with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
    rows.append(line.strip().split())` However, this still does not adress the actual question how to extract certain columns, especially with regards to the problem about different row lengths....

Answer (score 0):

I have stored given data in "data.txt". Try below code once.

```
res=[]
arr=[]
lines = open('data.txt').read().split("\n")
for i in lines:
    arr=i.split(" ")
    res.append(arr) 
for i in range(len(res)):
    for j in range(len(res[i])):
       print(res[i][j],sep=' ', end=' ', flush=True)
    print()
```